# update timestamp column when any data in a row is modified in sharepoint list

Tags: list, timestamp

I would like a column to track changes to my sharepoint list, by writing a timestamp of when a change in any row of any of the columns took place.

Is this possible?

Peter

Answer (score 2):

A row is basically the columns in a list item.  The Modified column (which is a Date type) would update whenever a list item was changed.  Modified is included as a default column in a list so you should not have to add anything.   Does that meet your needs?

Comment: I can't seem to find a "Modified" column. I can only see the columns which I created myself. Would you care to elaborate? :)

Comment: Figured out that these meta columns are hidden by default. Incredible that there is so poor documentation regarding this, but all I had to do was click on a column, then column settings, then show/hide columns, then select the meta columns (hidden by default) you would like to display then click apply up top. Then they show up :)

Comment: Another way to access the meta columns: select "All Items" dropdown in the ribbon -> Edit current view.